# Cannot get divs to stack horizontally and be 100% of screen, in mobile view, while staying as 3 side-by-side in desktop

Tags: css

I have tried several solutions offered on this forum and none have worked.
Here is my code (I want 3 separate divs next to each other in desktop view, but to stack and fill 100% wide in mobile, on top each other)

Mobile Layout: 480px and below:

```
.gridContainer {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
        }
#bnr1 {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #9C0;
    clear: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#maincontent {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#footer {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#bnrpic {
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-transition: border-top-width, opacity 2000s ease-in-out 2s;
    -moz-transition: border-top-width, opacity 2000s ease-in-out 2s;
    -ms-transition: border-top-width, opacity 2000s ease-in-out 2s;
    -o-transition: border-top-width, opacity 2000s ease-in-out 2s;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    text-align: left;
        }
#LayoutDiv2 {
    text-align: left;
    }
#LayoutDiv3 {
       text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question; you're missing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

give the divs a `float: left` and `width: 33,3%`, then a `width: 100%` under breakpoint

```
.class {
   width: 33.3%;
   float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .class {
      width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v6vk8g2m/)

Answer (score 0):

you may use "vh" unit for height property. 
Basically it sets the size of your elements size via height of browser.
For details you can check.
https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Check this example code:

```
<div class="main">1</div>
<div class="main">2</div>
<div class="main">3</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
/*you have to reset browser to default to avoid problems*/
.main{
 width: 32%;
 height: 100px; /*any size you want*/
 background-color: black;
 float: left;

 /*Just for text and border*/
  border-right: 2px white solid;
  color: white;
  font-size: 600%;
  text-align: center; 
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 200px;/*define your min-height
    because your content could mess*/

  /*Just for text and border*/
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px white solid;
 } 
 }
```

As you see, I define a new style for devices up to 400px (with vh unit).
The result should seem like that:
https://codepen.io/coderdisco/pen/VWvRdK